# Docker permissions issue on Fedora 36

Tags: django, docker, pip

I am following a Docker / Django tutorial on Fedora 36. I am getting an error with `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt .` from within the Dockerfile. The error is: `The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt .' returned a non-zero code: 1` `exec /bin/sh: permission denied` Here is my docker file:

```
#Pull base image
FROM python:3.10.4-slim-bullseye
#Set enviornment variables
ENV PIP-DISABLE_PIPVERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

#Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#Copy project
COPY . .
```

Here is the requirements.txt file:

```
asgiref==3.5.2
#backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
Django==4.0.5
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

Comment: That error is from the shell telling you that pip failed. There should be a message from pip that gives a bit more information.

Comment: @HansKilian Sorry, I missed part of the error message. I just revised my post and also included the requirements.txt file.  The error is a permissions issue.

Comment: I think you don't need the extra dot for the pip install command, you just need to provide the requirements.txt file.

Comment: @user3224454 Thanks for the answer but that did not work. I was in error about the extra dot. I am going to edit my post to remove it.

Comment: If I remove the period at the end of the command, then it works for me.

Comment: Also what image are you using, for example with python:3 the Dockerfile works, you can check if you add FROM python3 in the start of the Dockerfile.

Comment: @HansKilian It's still giving the same error for me. I am sure it's a permissions issue. I am just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @user3224454 I added the base image to the post.

Comment: Also try to build the image with --no-cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker quit working correctly after the Fedora 36 upgrade. My solution was to completely uninstall Docker and reinstall it per instructions at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/fedora/

Uninstall old versions:

```
sudo dnf remove docker \
                  docker-client \
                  docker-client-latest \
                  docker-common \
                  docker-latest \
                  docker-latest-logrotate \
                  docker-logrotate \
                  docker-selinux \
                  docker-engine-selinux \
                  docker-engine
```

Set up the repository

```
sudo dnf -y install dnf-plugins-core    
sudo dnf config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/docker-ce.repo
```

Install the Docker Engine

```
sudo dnf install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

Start Docker

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: This saved my bacon as of Fedora 37. Thank you Mike!